# .htaccess redirect all index.html to parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I need to redirect all index.html like this

**Original URL**

1. www.example.com/lp/index.html
2. www.example.com/sytem/index.html

**Desired URL**

1. www.example.com/lp
2. www.example.com/sytem

I used the follwing, it redirects successfully but 404 page

```
RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$  [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right, what you did looks like a copy paste error to me. Your first RewriteRule is missing a parameter - there should be a slash before `[R=301,L]`

Your htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Reference:
http://dense13.com/blog/2012/10/29/removing-index-html-with-mod_rewrite-in-htaccess/

Comment: the url got redirect but with respone `Status Code: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: It's possible that your browser caches 301 redirects. Did you try again after clearing the browser cache, or trying the same with another browser, which does not have cache yet for your site?

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: the url got redirect but with respone `Status Code: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index\.html [PT,L]
```

PT and L are rewrite flags, for more details about them check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

why not redirect **index.**(anything) ?  like   index.php?   index.xhtml?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

or to base it from the initial URL request only (to avoid conflicts with other rewrite rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```